# Leader Selection Form Swarm of Agents NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to implement a scenario that all agents in NetLogo simulation should report the number of agent in their neighbour upto 3 patches in radius. And then  top 3 of them having largest number of agents in its radius should  'set  is-leader? true ' . As i am using ' turtles-own [ is-leader? ] ' .

```
to setup
ca
ask n-of 30 patches [sprout 1 [
 set size .8
 ]
] 
end
to go
fd 0.5
lt random 20
choose-leader
end

to choose-leader


end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

- turtles have variable "is-leader?" set to false.
- turtles at each tick move in the random way you decided, then set their "is-leader?" variable to false
- the procedure choose-leader is executed. It chooses the 3 turtles with the higher number of neighbors in radius 3 and set their "is-leader?" to true.

code:

```
 turtles-own[
   is-leader?
]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 30 patches [sprout 1 [set size .8 set is-leader? false]] 
end

to go
  ask turtles[
     fd 0.5
     lt random 20
     set is-leader? false
  ]
  choose-leader

end

to choose-leader

   ask max-n-of 3 turtles [count turtles in-radius 3] [set is-leader? true]

end
```